# List docker images in Nexus repository from a remote machine

Tags: docker, nexus

I am wanting to list all the docker images in a particular location on Nexus. Both these technologies are new to me which is making it difficult to figure out what to do.

I am on a linux machine with docker installed & running this command -

```
docker image ls --all xx.xx.xx.xx/myorg/nodelms*
```

where xx.xx.xx.xx is the IP address of Nexus

Nothing is listed in the output as shown below.

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE
```

Please can someone guide me on how to achieve what I am after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker image ls` only interacts with the local docker engine, telling you about images that have been previously pulled. To query a remote registry, you'll want to hit the registry API. That API is documented by the [OCI distribution-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md#content-discovery). You could run some curl commands to implement this, though auth is typically the complicated part. Various projects exist to access this API, including go-containerregistry's crane (by Google), skopeo (by RedHat), and [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/) (by me). An example of using regclient's `regctl` for this looks like:

```
$ regctl tag ls localhost:5000/library/debian
10
10-slim
10.3
10.3-slim
10.4
10.4-slim
10.5
10.5-slim
10.6
10.6-slim
10.7
10.8
6
7
8
9
buster-slim
latest
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
curl -u user_name:password -X GET(optional here, as GET method was chosen by default) 'ip_nexus_repo:port/service/rest/v1/repositories'
```

And then check list of images of specific repo: `v1/components?repository=repository_name`